# Can I create a caller workflow with on.manual_dispatch that presents the input context from the called workflow directly to the user?

Tags: input, github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

I have a reusable workflow that uses `input.choice` (and other inputs) which will likely need to change again and again. This workflow is called from a bunch of other repos with caller worklflows that use `on.workflow_dispatch`. I know how to use `jobs.<job_id>.with` to pass inputs but everytime I change the reusable workflow's input context I'd have to go through every single caller and change it. Is their a way to present the input context of the reusable workflow directly to the user when they manually run the caller workflows?

##### How I'm imagining it:

caller:

```
name: caller

on:
   workflow_dispatch:
      inputs: #directly form reusable.yml

jobs:
   call_workflow:
      uses: org/repo/.github/workflows/reusable.yml@main
      with: #some way to do this dynamically
```

callee:

```
name: reusable

on:
   workflow_call:
     inputs: #should be handled by caller as if callee was manually started
        choose:
           type: choice
           options:
           - one
           - two
           required: True
        text:
           type: string
           required: True

jobs:
   dostuff:
      ...
```

To phrase it differently: Is their a way for the caller workflow to inherent the input context of the called workflow dynamically?

Comment: There isn't something like [`jobs.<job_id>.secrets.inherit`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsecretsinherit) for the `inputs` context. However, you may utilize [`toJson`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) function to pass the complete `inputs` context from caller to callee. For example, the callee may have `with: inputs` and the caller can then pass `with: inputs: ${{ toJson(inputs) }}`. In the callee, you may handle it according to your use case.